# Целочисленное деление с округлением вверх (без цикла и условии if)

Tags: алгоритм

Как округлить число вверх, не используя циклы, условные операторы и готовые функции (ceil)?

Answer (score 1):

Для целочисленного деления это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
(num + div - 1)/div
```

Где `num` - делимое, `div` - делитель.
Или так:

```
(num + div/2)/div
```

Comment: второе округлит к ближайшему (и не совсем правильно), а не вверх...

Comment: @Fat-Zer , вы совершенно правы. Но я надеялся, что ваше замечание сделает Amir Saken.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!